# Making Keras regression model with time series data with Deep Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to make regression with Keras DNN that has time series in it. Is stock price prediction. My dataframe has 1300 rows. This it the sample:

```
        Date    Open    Close   High    Low     High-Low Day    Price
0   2016-04-11  94.19   93.95   94.34   93.75   0.59    0       422.7
1   2016-04-12  93.97   93.96   94.39   93.63   0.76    1       427.3
2   2016-04-13  94.05   94.74   94.85   94.00   0.85    2       426.7
3   2016-04-14  94.81   94.90   95.20   94.68   0.52    3       425.4
4   2016-04-15  94.94   94.70   95.05   94.51   0.54    4       429.9
```

I made the column "Day" that goes from 0 to `len(df)` because I do not know how to work with a date.
My Keras model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim = features.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(400, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

I'm using the mean absolute squared error.

```
opt = SGD(lr = 0.00025, momentum = 0.01)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['mape'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta = 0.02, patience = 300, verbose=1, mode='auto')
history = model.fit(features, results, validation_split = 0.1, shuffle = False, epochs = 750, batch_size=50, verbose=2, callbacks=[es])

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=50)
print()
print(history.history.keys())
print()
print(score) #[99.96269438797283, 99.9627]

print('Test loss:', score[0],  'Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The problem is that my losses are not changing, it's always the same.
So I wanted to ask you, what am I doing wrong?
Why my network does not learn anything.

How can I check accuracy and loss?
Im using this to plot the learning curve:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8), dpi= 100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()


# summarize history for loss
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(13,9), dpi= 100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

But I always get two flat (horizontal) lines.

Ok, so If I change activation function to "relu" it will work much better but my `MAPE` is around 50, and thats a lot.
Are there any steps that I have missed? Should I use "Adam" or "SGD" for optimizer, should I use any other activation function, should shuffle be True or False? Is 1300 rows enough?

Comment: You should probably remove the softmax activation from the output layer if this is meant to be a regression model and not a multi-class classification model.

Comment: `Dense(1, activation='softmax')` is causing model to output 1s (ones) everytime. So you are just throwing away what you learn and output a vector of 1s (ones) everytime.

Comment: But what should I do? How should I make regression models?
I have read on their official docs that it should be 1

Comment: Yes the number of neurons should be 1 if the model is expected to return only 1 output, it's just the activation that is incorrect and definitely cannot be used in combination with the MAPE as a loss function. If you delete `activation='softmax'` your code should work, assuming that the features and target are in the correct format.

Comment: Ok, so If I change activation function to "relu" it will work? But have I made the model good?
 Are there any steps that I have missed? Should I use "Adam" or "SGD" for optimizer, should I use any other activation function, should shuffle be True or False? Is 1300 rows enough?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your last layer activation from `softmax` to `linear`. Try this

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation=None))
```

Comment: Let me know if it works. You may also need to do normalization. Ref: [code example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/).

Comment: Its a little better. MAPE is around 35. Can you please post how should my code look like with normalization. Because I'm passing features and results (full dataset) to model.fit and then I define validation_split = 0.1, and below to model.evaluate im passing x_test and y_test. I think that Im doing something wrong there. Whats the correct order of doing that?

Comment: I couldn't just post any normalization step, I need data to check first. You can check that code example above, there are some data preprocessing steps.

Comment: By normalization, do you think about sklearn's normalizer?
I worked witht that, and standard scaler etc. but I do not know how to add them in Keras model. I think that Im doing something wrong with train test  data. Im passing full data to fit the model, and then test data to evaluate it.

Comment: If possible just add some sample data or similar, then people can able to help. From this point, it's hard.

Comment: I have added sample data at beginning, do you want csv file?

Comment: Why the `suffle=False` in your `model.fit`! It should be `True`.

Comment: Because Im doing the time series prediction *(stock prediction), I guess that order of the data is important, because of that i set it as false. Is that correct

Comment: I don't have much hands-on experience with time series problems. But looking at some [code examples](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/) on this, I don't see you have to.